# MVC.NET: How to bundle the files on page instead of bundle.config

Tags: bundling-and-minification

When we define our own bundles we do in Bundle.Config, and when we are working in a team and using SVNs but still there are problems that developers can't make the files synch. To avoid this I want to bunlde the js and css in the separate file or even on the page.

I tried this:

```
BundleCollection bundles = new BundleCollection(); bundles.Add(new  
ScriptBundle("~/bundles/LogInJs").Include(
        "~/resources/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/resources/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
        "~/resources/Scripts/customJs/bootstrap.min.js" 
}

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/LoginStyle").Include(
           "~/resources/Style/customCss/bootstrap.css",
           "~/resources/Style/customCss/font-awesome.min.css"
}
```

But its not working, I am sure I am doing something wrong here. any thoughts or suggestions please.